# Is it idiomatic to use the From/Into trait for fallible conversions?

Tags: rust, idioms

I am working on the auth system for my API using jwt and have the following two types:

```rust
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct UserClaims {
    email: String,
    exp: usize,
    sub: String,
}

#[derive(Serialize)]
struct AccessToken(String);
```

Now I want to express the fact that an access token can be "converted" to a claims object. So I decided to implement the following:

```rust
impl From<AccessToken> for UserClaims {
    fn from(token: AccessToken) -> Self {
        // ... NOTE: this is fallible i.e actually returns a `Result`
    }
}
```

But I realized the code that decodes the token is fallible and returns a `Result`, now I can probably change the `impl` block to something like: `impl Into<Result<UserClaims, SomeError>> for AccessToken` but is this an idiomatic use of these traits? or would it be better if I just used regular methods?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, in fact, the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) specifically call out this use case.

> **Note: This trait must not fail.** The `From` trait is intended for perfect conversions. If the conversion can fail or is not perfect, use [`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.TryFrom.html)

The `TryFrom` trait (and its blanket companion `TryInto`) is intended to capture conversions that are fallible. It looks like this.

```
pub trait TryFrom<T> {
  type Error;

  fn try_from(value: T) -> Result<Self, Self::Error>;
}
```

So the "error" type is built into the trait. You get to specify that this conversion is fallible with a specific error type, and then `try_from` (and, again, by extension `try_into`) returns a `Result` where the conversion either succeeded or returned a value of your error type of choice.

So your proposed `From` would look like

```
impl TryFrom<AccessToken> for UserClaims {
  type Error = SomeError;

  fn try_from(token: AccessToken) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: That should be `try_from` in the last snippet, right?